# How to get rid of Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes in NuxtJs

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

Getting > `Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes:` when I am putting two `li` elements in else or if condition, as follows.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav language">
  <li><nuxt-link :to="switchLocalePath('en')"> <img src="~/assets/images/english.svg"> English</nuxt-link></li>
  <li><nuxt-link :to="switchLocalePath('ar')"> <img src="~/assets/images/arabic.svg"> العربية</nuxt-link></li>
  <li><nuxt-link to="#"> | </nuxt-link></li>
  <template v-if="$auth.loggedIn">
    <li><nuxt-link to="/profile"> Profile </nuxt-link></li>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <li><nuxt-link to="/signin"> Sign In </nuxt-link></li>
    <li><nuxt-link to="/signout"> Sign Out </nuxt-link></li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

[image]

Is it allowed to use more than one `li` element in the template tag using if/else? If not then how can I achieve this task?

**Updated:**
If I am wrapping my whole ul into client-only, this hides the error.

```
<client-only>
  <ul>
   ....
  </ul>
</client-only>
```

Is it OK, or are there any other best practices?

Comment: do `<li v-if="$auth.loggedIn">` instead

Comment: Feel free to check [this blog post about hydration](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/vue-hydration-error/)